# Selenium - How to use JavascriptExecutor in a JS test file?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to write a Javascript test script. I'm unsure how I can reference and use the JavascriptExecutor in an Javascript file.  How do I reference / instantiate it in Javascript?  I'm using FF.
Any sample code would be appreciated.
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert your JavaScript code inside the tests, **you don't need JavaScriptExecutor for that**.

Actually, JavaScriptExecutor is used to run JavaScript inside the browsers by WebDriver in Java environment as Java is a server side language and do not deal directly with browsers. This is done using the [executeScript](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and [executeAsyncScript](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) methods.

Same thing is implemented in C# using [IJavaScriptExecutor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

**Edit:**

To scroll to an ID, you can use one of the below code directly in your tests:

`window.scroll(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);`

`window.location.hash = '#ID';`

`document.getElementById('ID').scrollIntoView(true);`

```
var divPosition = $('#divId').offset();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow");
```

Comment: I need the feature to scroll to an ID. That is not visible.

Comment: I think the only way to do that is with the JavaScriptExecutor?

Comment: The only way to do that in Java/C# is JavaScriptExecutor, but in Javascript just write the script in the test itself.

Comment: I get window not defined

Comment: window.scroll(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);

Comment: @Jon did u try all of the above 4 code, all not working?

Comment: I added it to my javascript.. but get window not defined. Any ideas? thx

Comment: @Jon try 'document.getElementById('ID').scrollIntoView(true);' . Better update the question with code for what u have tried and what error u got?